# alarm is not working in the app

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I am trying to fire an alarm at a user-specified time. So I have `timepickerdialog` from which the user will select the time. It shows me the toast that alarm is set  for the specified time, but it is not working. Below is the code.

This is my MainActivity.

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
@Override
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                hours = hourOfDay;
                minutes = minute;

                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
                calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.ALARM_SERVICE);
                am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Alarm has been set for "+hours+":"+minutes,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, hour, minute, false);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select time");
        timePickerDialog.show();
```

This is my AlarmReceiver.class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Uri alarmRingtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if(alarmRingtone == null){
            alarmRingtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }

        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context,alarmRingtone);
        ringtone.play();
    }
```

This is my AndroidManifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: give permission android.permission.SET_ALARM

Answer (score 1):

Please try with following code it will be work for you

```
/**
     * Method for start Alarm on Every minute
     *
     * @param minutes Minute when you want to start after current time
     * @param context
     */
    public static void startAlarm(Context context, int minutes) {
        Logger.print("AlarmReceiver startAlarm  called");
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent.setAction("testAPP");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 123451, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        long alarmPeriodicTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + (minutes*60*1000);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            manager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        } else {
            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmPeriodicTime, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

In the My receiver, I am calling same again

```
 startAlarm(context, Prefs.getLocationUpdateInterval(context));
```

Comment: Is it repeating?

Comment: For repeat put same code in your broadcast receiver, it will work

Comment: What is WakefulBroadcastReceiverService.class? Is it the same as AlarmReceiver class? Also, where should I be writing this method - MainActivity or AlarmReceiver class?

Comment: Yes it is the same AlarmReceiver.

Comment: please check now.

Comment: I cannot locate Utils and Constant library in my android project

Comment: What is Prefs.getLocationUpdateInterval?

Comment: That is the time which when  you want to repeat alarm.

Comment: So I want it to fire when the user set it at the specified time and every day at the same time. So should I pass the time which the user selects from the timepickerdialog?

Comment: Yes exactly what i am saying

Comment: So suppose the time right now is 17:05 and I want the alarm to fire at 17:10. How will I pass that as an argument?

Comment: Then you need to just pass as 5 minutes like  startAlarm(context, 5); because time difference from the current time to wake up time is 5minute